# Child component cant get array from its parent after removing an element.

Tags: arrays, angular, components

I'm a beginner to angular. I've got small ap with 3 components. 
One component is just input and button which sends input value to the parent, and parent adds the incoming input to an array which is send forward to child where I want to print out all objects of array. Whenever I run function remove() and try to add another element afterwards by add() it is added only to listOfTasks but it's not added to taskList. Can someone explain why?

Component with input:

```
  export class InputTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('newTask') newTask = new EventEmitter<string>();
  input: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   add() {
        this.newTask.emit(this.input);
        this.input='';
}
```

Main component:

```
 export class AppComponent {

  addedTask: string;
  listOfTasks: string[]=[];
  doneTask:string[]=[];


  constructor()  {
  }

  receiveNewTask(event) {
    this.addedTask=event;
    this.listOfTasks.push(this.addedTask);
  }
  receiveDoneTask(event) {
    this.doneTask.push(event);
  }

}
```

Second child:

```
    export class AddTaskComponent implements OnInit {


  @Input('tasksFromInput') taskList: string[];
  @Output('doneTask') doneTask = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  done(task) {
    this.doneTask.emit(task);

  }
  remove(task) {
    this.taskList = this.taskList.filter(e => e !== task);
    console.log(this.taskList);
  }
```

HTML of main component:

```
  <div>
  <div style="float:left; width:300px;">
    <app-input-task (newTask)="receiveNewTask($event)">

    </app-input-task>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:300px;">
    <app-add-task [tasksFromInput]="listOfTasks" (doneTask)="receiveDoneTask($event)">

    </app-add-task>
  </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:300px;">
      <app-done-task [done]="doneTask">

      </app-done-task>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this on StackBlitz, it would be easier to understand.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-barw7d              The thing is after I remove or press done button i cant add any tasks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how change detection works in Angular. You have arrays in several places and use them as inputs for components.

When you add a task to them you use the push method which adds the element to the array, but the array itself is the same one, basically the reference does not change.

When you want to add an object to the tasks list and trigger the change detection you have to create a new array, for example:

`this.listOfTasks = [...this.listOfTasks, this.addedTask];`

In this way the example app will work. More info about [change detection in Angular here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).